# How to get result from async function within synchronous function in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest, asynchronous, synchronization

Background: I need to use the result from asynchronous function `getHolidaysByYear` within sync function `isHoliday`, because of sync function is a part of the component. But asynchronous function is run later than sync function, how to get result from asynchronous function before continue sync function.

The example:

```
//Call rest to get range of holidays
async function getHolidaysByYear(year : number) : Date[] {
    //I use other rest server to get range
    let dates = await api.request(year);
    if(dates !== undefined)
    {
        console.log("holidays : " + dates.length);
        return dates;
    }
    else
    {
        return [];
    }
}

//Function is used in component
function isHoliday(current : Moment) : booleant {
    //other parts (cache and other parts)
    let year : number = current.toDate().getFullYear();
    let dates : Date[] = [];
    console.log("before : " dates.length);
    getHolidaysByYear(year).then(values => {dates = values});
    console.log("after : " dates.length);
    //other parts (cache and other parts) ...
}
```

Now I get the next console result:

```
before : 0
after : 0
holidays : 143
```

But I want to get something like this:

```
before : 0
holidays : 143
after : 143
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the "after" part inside the "then" block to make sure the "after" part get executed after `getHolidaysByYear`.

```
getHolidaysByYear(year)
  .then(values => {
    dates = values

    console.log("after: ", dates.length)
    // other parts
});
```

but if you don't like to put all the other stuff inside the then block, you can turn isHoliday function into async function.

```
//Function is used in component
async function isHoliday(current : Moment) : boolean {
  //other parts (cache and other parts)
  let year : number = current.toDate().getFullYear();
  let dates : Date[] = [];
  console.log("before : " dates.length);
  dates = await getHolidaysByYear(year)
  console.log("after : " dates.length);
  //other parts (cache and other parts) ...
}
```